# WHich ETL starting point is the easiest and most efficient for SQL Server Integration?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2014

I'm new to the ETL world and I'm trying to arrange for a data file to be sent to us from another company so that then it can be ETLed to a data warehouse. I'll be developing the ETL via Integration Services on SQL Server 2014. Basically, I have five types of records: account records (meta records related to a person's account), purchase records, etc.

TO make it easier, Account records just give information about the account holder (name, account id, sex, etc), and purchase records show a history of purchases and their amounts, etc

My Question is: the company sending us the records is asking me this: how do you want the records arranged?

1. Multi-header/trailer: each header indicates the type of records we are getting (header1 will be Account)
2. Multiple files (each type of records will be on a separate file)
3. Mention the person followed by the records that belong to him.

For example:

```
Person X
Account Records....
Purchase Records...
... 
Person Y
Account Records....
Purchase Records...
```

Comment: I dont really understand you problem, you have to explain way more. But as far as I understand, the way to go is choice 2. Have many files with the same format and the processing will be the same always. You just have to process each file separetely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SSIS as your ETL tool, **always** go for the same format within the file.

SSIS can handle Header records (in that we can skip them). It *cannot* handle trailer records (because our columns are no longer consistent.

1 and 3 both violate the above.

As SSIS gives you access to the .NET framework, you *can* write all the custom parsing and then you can handle any file format, even a 1 or 3 but that's rarely a wise investment on the part of your company unless you're just flush with .NET devs who want to write ETL. Use the Out Of the Box components until they don't meet the task at hand and then use script Tasks or Components to compensate. When that's the starting place for your package, it is usually fraught with peril.

Comment: Excellent answer, but can you have more than one header records skipped? Specifically, if I have one header record/line (that mentions details about the file) and if I have ANOTHER header record/line that mentions the column names, is this supported? The reason I ask is that when I tried to look this up quickly, it only gave me a checkbox option ("First Row contains column names?"). Thank you very much

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!! Nobody has .NET skills at my company, including myself. I find it strange that SSIS doesn't allow for such a basic functionality, isn't that a common thing? Also, I've seen some extracts that start with H for header, R for records and T for trailer. SSIS doesn't have this?